# enabling max-width in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've implemented max-width so that content for .name takes up 1 line vs 2 lines. So instead of:

Bob
Lee

it correctly looks

Bob Lee

in other browsers. e.g. chrome

I've found that IE doesn't support max-width though - how can I fix things so that content for .name similarly takes up just 1 line in IE too?

I've tried

```
article .picture {
 width: expression(22 + "px");
 }
```

but this didn't do anything.

```
 .group {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
       -ms-flex-align: center;
           align-items: center;
   margin, padding: 0px;
  }

    .group img {
    width: 22px;
  }

    article .picture {
    max-width: 22px;
     width: expression(22 + "px");
  }

   .name {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 17px;
  }


  <article> 
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/img.jpg);"></div>
    </a>
      <div class="text">
      <div class="A">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="B">Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="C">
      <div class="group">
      <div class="picture"><img src="img/sample.jpg"></div> 
      <div class="name">Bob Lee</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </article>
```

Comment: Which version of internet explorer is your trouble with? Expression() is something i have not seen for a long time.

Comment: I believe it's not working in IE 9, 10, 11.  It's okay if IE 9 doesn't work, but I'd like it to work on IE 10 and 11.     Expression () --> i saw it on a blog post and tried it

Comment: @roarsandmeows why don't you use `white-space: nowrap;` to avoid name wrapping to second line?

Comment: @OzgurSar it's b/c sometimes name is long so it actually needs to take up 2 lines.

Comment: @roarsandmeows but in the first line in your question you wrote like you are trying to avoid name splitting into multiple lines. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I'm not very familiar with IE specific css

Comment: @OzgurSar Yes sorry i wasn't being super clear.  So when names are short e.g. Bob Lee, it'd be 1 line.  But when names are long e.g. Benjamin Franklin  this can't be fit in 1 line, so would need to be 2 lines.    Now if I use white-space: nowrap,  Benjamin Franklin will have to be in 1 line too, but this will look odd

Comment: If we refer to the [docs](https://caniuse.com/?search=max-width) we can see that the `max-width` is supported in IE 11. I try to test your sample code with the long name you posted in the comment. This is the [test result](https://imgur.com/a/jpunndN). It does not looks odd and gives a similar result to other browsers. If possible, can you please provide the snapshot of the issue from the IE browser and from any other browser where it looks correctly? It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  Sure, here it is  https://imgur.com/a/A3oJ5TO  I'm unable to find out which version of IE i've tested this on b/c "about internet explorer" in settings is disabled  (that's how you find out which version).  Hmm the doc says IE 9 also supports max-width, but I don't think that's true - I've also tested IE 9 here 
 https://www.browserling.com/internet-explorer-testing  but 2 lines here too.

Comment: The test result you have shown in the previous comment is directly from the IE 11 browser? If yes, I suggest you provide the proper code to reproduce the issue, as with the sample code in the original post we are not able to produce the issue. Another thing I want to suggest that try to make a test with the actual browser on your machine instead of testing the issue virtually by using some sites. Please note that at present only IE 11 supported.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  I did test it on an actual browser - I can't find out whether it's 11 or another version b/c "about internet explorer" in settings is disabled.  If max-width really works for IE 11, I'm assuming it's IE 10.  Is there a way to make it work in IE 10?

Comment: As I informed you at present only IE 11 is supported. If you think you have an issue with the IE 11 browser, I suggest you please provide the accurate code sample as the styling in your test result looks much different than the test result I got from the code posted in the original post.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT https://jsfiddle.net/benjaminana77/8eLw4s1y/4/  here's a fiddle

Comment: @roarsandmeows, please refer to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to check and test the sample code in the IE 11 browser and found that `-ms-flex:  1; and flex:  1;` in the `.name` class was causing this issue.

IE 11 has some knows issues with the [Flex](https://caniuse.com/flexbox). This is can be the reason for this issue.

If you comment or remove the flex in the `.name` class then the issue will be fixed.

.name class:

```
.name {
    letter-spacing: 2.2px; 
   -webkit-box-flex:  1;
   /*-ms-flex:  1;
   flex:  1;*/
   line-height: 1.6;
  }
```

Output:

[image]