# Max-width on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm having trouble getting max-width to work in IE. Is there a way to get max-width to work on IE?

This is what it looks like on other browsers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJl0V.png)

This is what it looks like on IE:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqRSP.png)

here's HTML code

```
  <div class="grid menu-content" id="menu1-content">

    <article> 
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/test.jpg);">
      </div>

      <div class="text">
      <div class="company-name">Name</div>
      <div class="company-description">Basdfasdfasdf
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="founders">
      <div class="founder">
      <div class="picture"><img src="img/test.jpg" alt="asdf"></div> 
      <div class="name">FIRSTNAME LASTNAME</div>
      </div>
       <div class="founder">
      <div class="picture"><img src="img/test.jpg" alt="sdf"></div> 
      <div class="name">FIRSTNAME LASTNAME</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </article> 

 <article> 
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/test.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="text">
      <div class="company-name">name</div>
      <div class="company-description">asdfasdf
</div>
      </div>
       <div class="founders">
      <div class="founder">
      <div class="picture"><img src="img/breadfinance-founder.jpg" alt="Bread Finance Founder JOSH ABRAMOWITZ
"></div> 
      <div class="name">BEN JIN
</div>
      </div>
      </div>   
  </article> 



   <article> 
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/test.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="text">
      <div class="company-name">asdfasdf</div>
      <div class="company-description">asdfasdfasdf
 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="founders">
      <div class="founder">
      <div class="picture"><img src="img/test.jpg" alt="asdf"></div> 
      <div class="name">KATIE KIM</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </article> 



   <article> 
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(img/test.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="text">
      <div class="company-name">asdfasdf</div>
      <div class="company-description">asdfasdf
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="founders">
      <div class="founder">
      <div class="picture"><img src="img/test.jpg" alt="asdfasdf"></div> 
      <div class="name">DEBBIE KIM</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </article> 


  </div>
```

here's CSS

```
   .name {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2.2px;
    margin-left: 17px;

  }

    .founder img {
    width: 22px;
  }

  .founder {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
  }

    article .picture {
    max-width: 22px;
  }
.

  .company-name {
    margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        font-size: 22.5px;
  }

  .company-description {
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-bottom: 6px ;
  }


 .founders {
  position: absolute; 
 }



 .founder {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
       -ms-flex-align: center;
           align-items: center;
   margin, padding: 0px;
  }

  .name {
   letter-spacing: 2.2px;
     -webkit-box-flex:  1;
      -ms-flex:  1;
  flex:  1;
  line-height: 1.6;
  }

  .picture {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 22px;
    flex: 0 0 22px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .founder img {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }


   .founders {
  top: 99%;
 }




@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS */
    .grid article {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 150px;   
        -ms-flex-pack: start;
}

.grid article {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 150px;
        -ms-flex-pack: start;   
}

}
```

some more css that's probably not relevant

```
.grid {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;  
  display: grid;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
            justify-content: start; 
          justify-content: space-between;
  row-gap: 100px;

} 


.grid article {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
  -ms-flex-pack: start; 
}


.grid .photo {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

.grid .photo:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.grid a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;

}


 .grid article  {
  position: relative;
 }



  .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 100px;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: I try to run your sample code in IE 11 and in other browsers and I can notice the difference in the result at multiple places. If we talk about `max-width` then we can notice that you have used it in the `picture` class inside the `founder` class. When I try to check it using the developer tools in IE 11 then I noticed that `max-width` is applied. So here I want to confirm with you can you please highlight the problem in the snapshot of the issue? It can really help us to understand the issue properly as there is a difference with multiple elements in the test result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have created this new thread for the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368009/enabling-max-width-in-internet-explorer) that you had asked for before.

I have tested the sample code and found that `-ms-flex:  1; and flex:  1;` in the `.name` class is causing this issue.

IE 11 has partial support for the [Flex](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) due to some known issues. This can be a possible reason for this issue.

The issue can be fixed by commenting or removing the flex from the `.name` class.

.name class:

```
.name {
    letter-spacing: 2.2px; 
   -webkit-box-flex:  1;
   /*-ms-flex:  1;
   flex:  1;*/
   line-height: 1.6;
  }
```

Output:

[image]